Python: Detener función principal cuando se ejecute la excepción sin salir del programa
agradecería si pueden resolverme esta duda. Lo he puesto muy escueto, es un pequeño programa hecho con PySide y hago click en un botón con el evento click_boton que, entre otras cosas, comprueba si existe un documento (Lo hago así para no repetirlo a lo largo del programa con su try y except), si se ejecuta la excepción porque no existe el documento dentro de la función existeDocumento, quisiera que no continuara ejecutando el resto de código, que se parara pero sin salir del programa. Porque compruebo que, aunque se lance la excepción, se ejecuta el print ("no debe pasar si se ejecuta la excepción") de la función principal
Muchas gracias por vuestra atención
def existeDocumento (ruta:str):
     try:
          if os.path.exists(ruta):           
               return ruta
          else:
              raise Exception    
     except Exception:
            print ("Error")
         
          
def click_boton()
    ruta = "C:\\documento.txt"
    nombreFichero = existeDocumento (ruta)
    print ("no debe pasar si se ejecuta la excepción")


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No soy experto en python.. pero tu logica tiene dos problemas.. no queres que siga.. entonces que queres que haga?? y despues, si no queres que siga, tiene que pasar algo para que no siga...

Hola Antonio, bienvenido, la forma mas sencilla es colocar print ("no debe pasar si se ejecuta la excepción") dentro de if os.path.exists(ruta):.

Las excepciones son para manejar excepciones. El método os.path.exists() no genera ninguna excepción, por lo que rodearlo con try except no tiene ninguna utilidad.
Las situaciones normales deben manejarse a través de los valores retornados, indicando a través de ellos qué pasó.
Una primera aproximación es simplificar el método existeDocumento(), para que devuelva None si el documento no existe, lo cual puedes atrapar con un if en click_boton()
def existeDocumento(ruta: str):
    nombre = None
    if os.path.exists(ruta):
        nombre = ruta
    return nombre

def click_boton():
    ruta = "scratch_1.py"
    nombreFichero = existeDocumento(ruta)
    if nombreFichero:
        print("Resto del código")
    else:
        print("no debe pasar si se ejecuta la excepción")

Pero la realidad es que es complicarse inútilmente. Podemos eliminar por completo el método existeDocumento y preguntar directamente, reduciendo el código a
import os
    
def click_boton():
    ruta = "scratch_1.py"
    if os.path.exists(ruta):
        #   Caso existe
        print("Resto del código")
    else:
        #   Caso no exite
        print("Archivo no existe")


El except Exception está capturando la excepción que se lanza con raise, por eso el código no se comporta apropiadamente.
Se podría hacer algo así (devolver un string vacío si no existe la ruta):
def existeDocumento (ruta:str):
     try:
          if os.path.exists(ruta):           
               return ruta
          else:
              raise Exception    
     except Exception:
            print ("Error")
            return ""
         
          
def click_boton():
    ruta = "C:\\documento.txt"
    nombreFichero = existeDocumento (ruta)
    if nombreFichero != "":
      print ("no debe pasar si se ejecuta la excepción")
    else:
      print("Archivo no ok")

Otra forma de hacerlo podría ser capturar la excepción dentro de click_boton() en vez de hacerlo en existeDocumento()
